# расположение файлов зон dns linux

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

Когда я настраиваю файл зон днс, то по умолчанию выбираю каталог /etc/bind/ и все работает, но мне надо выбрать другое расположение, например, /my_zone/dns,  но после этого днс не работает. Заранее спасибо! Дистр - дебиан. Конфиги - default-zones - без изменений (по умолчанию), option - без изменений (по умолчанию), [image: named.conf]

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него дистрибутив линукса, какой named используется и как именно вы запускаете named. Также добавьте содержимое файлов `/etc/default/named`, `/etc/bind/named.conf`, `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`, `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`, `/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones`

Comment: изменил, в named.conf.local описана прямая зона и обратная, тип мастер и просто путь, где лежат настройки зон

Comment: Если вы ничего не изменили в конфигах, то как `named` узнает, что у вас база лежит в другом месте? Вам нужно в `named.conf.local` добавить `include "/my_zone/dns/zones.conf";` или как файл с описаниями зон у вас называется.

Comment: Пардон, не увидел ваш второй комментарий.

Comment: 1) Вместо картинки здесь должен быть текст! 2) Не вижу описанной проблемы! Куда и что вы пытались заносить?